# cannot connect and select 2 database in one php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_selectDb('cms',$con);
$con2=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_selectDb('cms2',$con2);
$memberId="Member0001";
$select2=mysql_query("select * from member_register where memberID='$memberId'",$con);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($select2);
?>
```

i got a code like above, select 2 database from 1 server, sure the code is right, but it appear

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in xxx on line xxx

Comment: does your code work without the two concurrent mysql connections?

Comment: Why on earth would You need two connections to the very same database server?

Comment: @shadyyx that's indeed a curious thing to do.

Comment: I doubt that. Possibly he misunderstood the connection and database selecting and thinks he need a connection to each different database on the same server. But this is not needed.

Comment: i saw some examples before, it work for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to maintain two connections to the same DB server with the same credentials. You can trivally use

```
SELECT db1.table.member_register, ...

SELECT db2.othertable.somefield, ...
```

using the same single connection. Two connections would only really be needed if you have to connect using DIFFERENT credentials.

In your case, since you're getting a 'boolean received', your query failed, and you simply assumed it succeeded (NOT a good idea). Try:

```
$select2=mysql_query("...",$con) or die(mysql_error());
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to find out WHY the query failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing the exact same connection details to `mysql_connect`, you'll get the same connection back. It's reusing existing connections. So you only have one connection, and your query fails because you're operating on the wrong database.

Use `... FROM database.table ...` in your queries to work across different databases on the same server.